# How to tell which RevMob version is currently installed in an app?

Tags: ios, revmob

It doesn't appear that RevMob embeds any explicit version information in their SDK (at least as far as 7.2.2 anyhow...).

How can you tell which version is actually installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the current version, include this line somewhere (like maybe after you setup RevMob)

```
[[RevMobAds session] printEnvironmentInformation];
```

And search for **SDK Version** in the output of the console.

Answer (score 1):

This has now changed to

```
  [RevMobAds printEnvironmentInformationWithAppID:@“your_app_ID”];
```

Comment: Umm - No it hasn't. That API call doesn't seem to exist and a Google search on it turns up one hit - this page.
Come to think of it - why would that call exist? Why would you need the App ID? It's running in the app which it knows about already...
Huh??